# Google reCaptcha is not defined when loaded from View Component

Tags: .net-core, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

I have an issue with reCaptcha when it is being loaded from a View Component (error message disappears if I move same form straight to the view).
I have reCaptcha library installed and am using  to implement it on a form. reCaptcha icon is showing up on a page (using V3 version) and form submits fine though, but in browser console I can still see an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: grecaptcha is not defined". Any idea how to resolve it?

Attaching an image of what AspNetCore.ReCaptcha adds to a form - input value is missing:
[image]

Comment: post the code of your view page with recaptcha code (js)

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi there is no manual JS. I only include <recaptcha language="SiteLang"  /> tag onto a form and AspNetCore.ReCaptcha library using settings from appsettings.json manages it itself. Added a screenshot of what is being added to a form. The thing is - reCaptcha works but I still see an error in browser's console which is weird.